# Restoring SVN repository from backups

Tags: svn, restore

I have been using Doug Hellmann's script to back up my repo for 2 years now, and I eventually lost my server hard drive. So I created a brand new repo on another machine, and attempted the restore command, which is:

```
gunzip -c `ls -tr dump*` | svnadmin load /home/svn/myproject
```

Only it doesn't work. It gives the response

```
<<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 917
svnadmin: File not found: transaction '0-1', path 'MineSweeper2/src/com/bytezone/minesweeper2/Game.java'
     * editing path : MineSweeper2/src/com/bytezone/minesweeper2/Game.java ...denis@ubuntu-lianli:~/SVN backups$
```

Can anyone explain what is wrong here? I have all the incremental backups ever made, surely this is the simplest case scenario.

Incidentally, is it possible to condense the dozen or so backup files into a single file before attempting the load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the backups are not being processed in the right order. `svnadmin load` reproduces the commits made in the repository to obtain a new copy. It seems is looking to commit a file modification but the file is not created yet because the commits are not in the proper order.

Comment: They should be in the right sequence (due to the -t option), but I did copy them to the new server first, so that may have reordered the time-stamps. I can't actually tell because they all seem to have the same time-stamp now.

Comment: I've seen many copy operations that have no considerations for the order when copying several files. Can't you use alphabetical order? What happens if you run the first dumps one by one?

Comment: Thank you. I 'touched' each of the files in order, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had to take a quick glace at his script. It looks like your doing a dumpfile only on the changes that took place since the last dump and then compressing them.

If that's the case, it should be possible to uncompress all the compressed backups, then concatenate them together ***in the right order*** to create a single valid dumpfile.

That ***in the right order*** is key. It looks like he keeps revision range in the dump file's name, but the revision numbers aren't zero filled which means sorting on the file names could be an issue.

It might be possible to sort the dump files based upon the `cdate` or `mdate` of the backup file, but that's sort of risky.

The name of the dump file is `${dumpfilename}-${repo_name}-${first}-${last}.${compress_ext}`, so it is possible to use the `-` as a field separator and sort on the 3rd field numerically.

```
sort -t - -k3,3n
```

That will put them in the correct order. Then you might be able to do something like this:

```
ls | sort -t - -k3,3n | while read backup
do
    bzcat $backup | svnadmin load $repos
done
```

Of course, that is completely untested because I hadn't tried Doug Hellmann's script, but that should be pretty close. You can combine everything in a single dump by doing this:

```
ls | sort -t - -k3,3n | while read backup
do
   bzcat $backup >> $dumpfile
done
```

Hope that works. Or, at least sends you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. I got it to work by changing the time-stamps manually, but it would have been easier if the names were zero-filled (as you suggested) and if the restore command sorted by name. I will try the combine step you suggested.

Comment: This is one of the times when Kornshell works better than Bash. In Kornshell, you can use `typeset` to declare a variable as fixed width zero filled variable. You do `typeset -Z first` and that would solve the problem. In Bash, you could use `printf` to format `first` to be zero filled, and that would really help. It's a minor change, but would make restoring so much easier. At least you wouldn't have to do the funky `sort` to get things in the right order. The `ls` would do it for you automatically. I'll suggest that to the author.